# How to assess whether Enum in EnumSet implements an interface

Tags: java, reflection

I need to write a function that accepts a class object and checks whether the argument is the EnumSet of enums implementing a specific interface.

Below is the function I currently have, but it only checks whether the class is an EnumSet, but I'm not able to assess it's Enum.

I have an interface

```java
public interface EnumWithOrdinalValue {
    long getOrdinalValue();
}
```

Some enums in code implement it, some don't and I need to filter out the later.

```java
public boolean isMatching(@Nonnull Class<?> aClass) {
        boolean retval = false;
        retval |= EnumSet.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
        return retval;
    }
```

Comment: In most situations, you should never have to check the `Class`. What's wrong with `void myRestrictedMethod(Set<? extends EnumWithOrdinalValue> set)`

Comment: Well, I'm trying to implement a very generic interface that is designed to process the public interfaces of other libraries. The problem I'm working on is to create a converter that will enable processing of EnumSets along with the other currently available classes. Changing to `retval |= EnumSet<? extends EnumWithOrdinalValue>.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);` gives a complie-time error `Cannot select from a paremetrized type`

Comment: Generic types are not part of the class. Both `List<String>` and `List<Integer>` are of the same type in runtime. You can only access generic type data of fields/methods and superclasses.
So in your case the only way would be to hope that there is at least one element in that set and check it type, and hope that all other elements are also of the same type. (or check them all)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I was hoping that I am missing something.